# Is there a way to pause sagas when the react-native app goes to background?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

Currently we check the store if the app is active:

```
function* cycleChatBadge() {

    let task;

    while (true) {
        const state = yield select(),
        isAppActive = isAppActiveSelector(state);

        if (!isAppActive) {
            yield call(delay, 8000)
            yield put({type: "CHAT_BADGE"});
            return;
        }

        const { input } = yield take('CHAT_BADGE');

        if (task) {
            yield cancel(task)
        }

        task = yield fork(getChatBadge)
    }
}
```

However, we wonder how optimised this approach is power-wise and whether checking the store every 5 seconds drains the battery. So we thought of pausing the root saga when the app goes to background. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

With the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) you can use document.hidden to check if the the app is in the background, and listen to the event visibilitychange to respond to changes.

Using that you can pause and resume your watch.

Anyhow, it would be more efficient if, instead of polling, you could manage to receive an event when the value changes.

Comment: My apologies, I should have specified in the title that we use React-Native. I fixed it now.